# Required GRUB modules for booting on mdadm RAID1

Tags: grub2, raid, mdadm, software-raid

I have a `mdadm`-managed RAID1 with a single EXT4 partition on it (having both the OS files and GRUB's files in `/boot/grub`), and I'd like to know what modules and what configuration do I need for GRUB to be able to boot from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The minimal required `grub.cfg` is the following :

```
set timeout=1

set root='mduuid/ce16c757e4752e4fa9a2fd4935df1aef'

menuentry 'Arch Linux' {
 linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=05dddf23-1d9f-417e-b3f8-2281a328dc0b rw
 initrd /boot/initramfs-linux.img
}
```

Yes, quite a bit different from the long stream of garbage that gets generated by `grub-mkconfig`, and as you can see, no modules seem to be necessary for this setup.

My particular setup is a single partition on an MBR-formatted disk, on which I assembled a RAID1 array and an EXT4 partition on that array.

The `root` variable is set to `mduuid/xxx` with the **UUID of the RAID array** which you can get by running `mdadm --examine /dev/sdX` on a disk or partition which is part of the RAID array. **This is not the UUID of the EXT4 filesystem on top of the RAID**, do not use the UUID reported by `lsblk` as it will only give you the UUID of the partition which won't work there.

You can also set the `root` variable to `md/...` with the label of your RAID array specified when creating it (`mdadm ... -N "some label" ...`). For other ways of specifying the root device, [check out the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Device-syntax).

The UUID on the kernel parameter's line, is **the UUID of the filesystem** which is on top of the RAID array - this one can be obtained by running `lsblk -o NAME,UUID` :

```
NAME                                      UUID
loop0                                     
└─loop0p2                                 ce16c757-e475-2e4f-a9a2-fd4935df1aef
  └─md127                                 05dddf23-1d9f-417e-b3f8-2281a328dc0b
loop1                                     
└─loop1p2                                 ce16c757-e475-2e4f-a9a2-fd4935df1aef
  └─md127                                 05dddf23-1d9f-417e-b3f8-2281a328dc0b
```

It's the one corresponding to the `mdXXX` device node - `05dddf23-1d9f-417e-b3f8-2281a328dc0b` in my case. Do not use the UUID of the underlying partition - `loopXp2` in this example.

---

As a bonus, here are some horrible shell scripts that *kinda work* if you want to experiment with GRUB in a QEMU/KVM virtual machine.

To create some raw disks, they have to be "raw" to be mountable on the host, you can't use qcow2 nor vmdk :

```
qemu-img create -f raw driveX.img XXXG # name and size
```

To start a VM with two disks, an ISO (in this case it's Archlinux but it can be anything) and basic network access :

```
/path/to/qemu-system-x86_64 -m 512 -cpu host -smp 2,cores=2,sockets=1 -machine q35,accel=kvm -balloon none -device ahci,id=ahci -drive if=none,file=drive1.img,format=raw,cache=none,aio=native,id=hdd1 -device ide-hd,bus=ahci.0,drive=hdd1 -drive if=none,file=drive2.img,format=raw,cache=none,aio=native,id=hdd2 -device ide-hd,bus=ahci.1,drive=hdd2 -drive if=none,file=arch.iso,format=raw,cache=none,aio=native,id=iso,snapshot=on -device ide-cd,bus=ahci.2,drive=iso -device pci-ohci,id=ohci -device usb-kbd,bus=ohci.0 -device usb-mouse,bus=ohci.0 -netdev user,id=net0 -device e1000-82545em,autonegotiation=on,netdev=net0 -realtime mlock=on
```

Script to mount the VM's partitions on the host, make sure to stop QEMU before running it to avoid corrupting the partitions :

```
losetup -P -f drive1.img # create loopback device nodes for the virtual disks
losetup -P -f drive2.img

mdadm --assemble /dev/md/root /dev/loop0p1 /dev/loop1p1 # assemble the RAID
# some distributions will auto-detect and assemble them so it sometimes fails
# running this script a second time usually succeeds in mounting it anyway
# if it failed the first time - I don't have time to fix the real issue

mount "/dev/md/root" rootfs # mount the root FS of the VM in this directory
```

Script to unmount, run this (multiple times just to be safe) before starting the VM back up :

```
umount rootfs # umount the FS

mdadm --stop /dev/md127 # sometimes the array appears under these names
mdadm --stop /dev/md126 # so we stop them as well just to be safe
mdadm --stop /dev/md/root # the correct name

losetup -D # detach all loop device nodes
```